# user permissions in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

I have a MariaDB 10.1 instance (Debian GNU/Linux 9 testing/unstable). It is meant to be a local network database server and nothing else. For resons beyond the scope of this question, that server must not host anything else except the database itself, which must listen on the server IP address (10.7.33.102).

If I connect to the database from the server shell, all is ok:

```
root@datangshan:~# mysql
[...]
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| drackmd            |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `drackmd` is the database other hosts need to use.
I've tried enabling `root` user to connect from another host with the following command:

```
grant all privileges on `*`.`*` to 'root'@'10.7.33.107' identified by 'secret' with grant option;
```

Then, from the server at 10.7.33.107, I can connect to the DB server, but the `root` user seems to lack some kind of permission:

```
root@10.7.33.107:~# mysql -h 10.7.33.102 -p
Enter password: 
[...]
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What command should I issue to the DB server to make `root` (or other users) see all databases and all tables in them?

Comment: The root account should be able to see all db's by default?

Comment: Is that a question? I don't know what's the default for the root account in mysql/mariadb, but I assume `all privileges` means just that...

Comment: What happends if you change the IP to %? Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Same problem even using % instead of the IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I got in the `#maria` channel on IRC:

```
drop user 'root'@'10.7.33.107';
drop user 'root'@'%';
flush privileges;
grant all on `*`.`*` to 'root'@'10.7.33.107' identified by 'secret' with grant option;
```

Please note the difference: it's a `grant all on ...` instead of a `grant all PRIVILEGES on...`.